# Add all values(doubles) for each key - in reference to an item with same key has already been added

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, tuples

I have multiple ID's in a file ( string - as keys) and i would like to add up all the values for each key(ID) and return as a dictionary of string and double.
to solve the problem -
I create a dictionary of ID(string) and Tuples (of double) because i have to perform some computations over two double before i add the value to the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, double> FinalValue = new Dictionary<string,double>();

Dictionary<string, Tuple<double, double>> TupleComputeResultByID = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<double, double>>();
 foreach (File row in rows)
```

i pre compute some values for doubles in tuples.
then i create a tuples of doubles and pass in the double values as double1 and double 2.

```
Tuple<double, double> TupleCompute = new Tuple<double,double>(double1,double2);
```

after this i try to add the tuplecompute to tuplecomputebyID.

```
 TupleComputeResultByID.Add(ID, TupleCompute);
```

but i get an error " an item with same key has already been added." how to do i sum all tuplecompute by each ID?

**More Info**

```
   foreach (string ID in TupleComputeResultByID.Keys)
        {

            Tuple<double, double> TupleCompute = TupleComputeResultByID[ID];
            double resut = double1.Item1 / double2.Item2;
            retValue.Add(ID, result);
        }
```

Comment: How `ID` is generated

Comment: Could you add the implementation of the foreach loop? How you populate your dictionary?

Comment: I have added more information for how ID is generated and the foreach loop. It's another loop in the same scope. Thank you for your hep in advance.